# What happens if Cloud Spanner fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Jan 2018 Spanner was down for 41 minutes in a region. What’s the alternative if Spanner goes down for 6 hours (assuming the worst case scenario) in a region.

Answer (score 2):

One of the specifications that you can see in the [Cloud Spanner Overview](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) is that is guaranteed max of 5 minutes of downtime (including planned downtime) on paper and in practice.

According to the [Cloud Spanner SLA](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/sla#previous_versions), there is specified a Monthly Uptime Percentage:

> Multi-Regional Instance -> >=99.999%
>
> Regional Instance -> 99.99%

Furthermore, in case Spanner was down for 6 hours in your region:

> 720 hours = total hours in a month
>
> 6 hours  = Downtime suffered
>
> Total Monthly Uptime Percentage = (720 - 6)/720  = **99.166%**

As the Monthly Uptime Percentage is between **99.0% and 99.99%,** and as specified in the documentation, you would get **10% of monthly bill** for Cloud Spanner Regional that will be credited to future monthly bills.

Answer (score 0):

There are effectively 2 alternatives:

Wait for the outage to recover...

Or

Import your last export (which you stored in a multi-region cloud storage bucket) into a new instance in another region.and point your application at that new instance.

This may take more time that the duration of the outage itself, and will require some complex re-syncing of data when the outage recovers.

There is also the preventative option of running a multi-region instance, but that can be very expensive, and has to be valued against the effective cost of an outage of your application.